# Should i call methods from class which is testing when i unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a database helper class which does insert,delete,save,connect,etc and i am writing test for this.However, when i write a test case should it be independent from testing class?

Should it be like:
1-)

```
@Test
public void testDelete() throws SQLException {
    // Given
    String dateStr = "09-May-2016";
    String word = "testWord";
    derbyDb.save(dateStr, word, 9);
    derbyDb.save(dateStr, word, 11);

    // When
    assertEquals(2, derbyDb.contain(dateStr, word));
    derbyDb.delete();

    // then
    assertEquals(0, derbyDb.contain(dateStr, word));
}
```

(You see on here,I used 'save' method. )

2-)

```
@Test
public void testDelete() throws SQLException {
    // Given
    String dateStr = "09-May-2016";
    String word = "testWord";
    PreparedStatement insertemp = conn
                .prepareStatement("insert into " + tableName + "(PUBLISHDATE,WORD,FREQUENCY) values(?,?,?)");
        insertemp.setString(1, dateStr);
        insertemp.setString(2, word);
        insertemp.setInt(3, frequency);
        insertemp.executeUpdate();

    // When
    assertEquals(2, derbyDb.contain(dateStr, word));
    derbyDb.delete();

    // then
    assertEquals(0, derbyDb.contain(dateStr, word));
}
```

Which one is true or better one?Or Should test unit be independent from other functions?

**EDIT:AssertEquals added before delete.**

**EDIT-2:In second option,there should be just one method which is 'delete' and will be indepent from other methods in class.So instead of contain method there should be a query.**

Comment: In either case, you should `assertEquals(2, derbyDb.contain(dateStr, word));` before the delete, so you know that the `delete` is the reason why it is zero after.

Comment: The first one would be clearer, if *testDelete* depends (for example with [TestNG "dependsOn"](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/annotations/Test.html#dependsOnMethods--)) on the test methods for `save`.

Comment: I would use the second option - you want to test one particular method, and the test for that method should be independent of other methods. Your example is simple, but if it becomes more complex your tests can become a tangled mess otherwise and it will not be clear what each test method exactly tests and depends on.

Comment: @Jesper I know what you mean, but note that the test calls both `delete` and `contain` in either case. I think that you should check both `save` and `contain` in the same way (either via the method, or via `conn`), if only `delete` is under test.

Comment: @AndyTurner In my opinion he should also not use `contain`, but check by doing a query in the test method if the database contains what's expected.

Comment: @AndyTurner I got what you said, when i ask question i tried to say should i only use testing method(delete)? Now,I understand the clear one(without risk) is second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you test the `save` method by itself too, I would use 1, in order that your `delete` tests don't break if you change the internal implementation of `save` to use some other mechanism.

Alternatively, you could do the insertion of the records to delete in a `@Before` method, in order that you simply have the `delete` in the actual test, to make it clear that it what is being tested in the method.

In either case, you should `assertEquals(2, derbyDb.contain(dateStr, word));` before the delete, so you know that the `delete` is the reason why it is zero after.

---

Google's Testing on the Toilet blog has a post related to this: ["Test Behavior, Not Implementation"](http://googletesting.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/testing-on-toilet-test-behavior-not.html).

> **Tests that are independent of implementation details are easier to maintain** since they don't need to be changed each time you make a change to the implementation. They're also easier to understand since they basically act as code samples that show all the different ways your class's methods can be used, so even someone who's not familiar with the implementation should usually be able to read through the tests to understand how to use the class.

Duplicating the database-level logic in the tests is testing implementation. You might need to make future changes like:

- Renaming database tables and columns;
- Changing the `derbyDb` class to use some other underlying storage - maybe you want an in-memory implementation of it, or something you can't connect to with JDBC.

If you've taken the second approach, you've got to go and fix the tests as well as the code under test.

If you've taken the first approach, you don't. Everything "just works" in the test - or it doesn't, but then you know it is a faulty implementation, not a faulty test.

Answer (score 1):

The latter one is safer, because in the first one you risk failure of the first method - if `derbyDb.save()` does not work properly you might end up with an error on the tested method which would be a false positive.

On the other hand if you have a separate test for the `.save()` method, using the first test is a lot clearer. After all if your build fails on one or two tests it doesn't make much difference - there's still code to fix. Just make sure you test all the methods that you use in other tests.

Probably a good approach would be to use only methods which were already tested in previous tests.